# Как не дублировать контент?

Tags: javascript, html

https://codepen.io/Olya097/pen/KKQxPYZ

а чтобы он заполнялся на всю ширину
тоесть не дублировать спаны

```html
<div class="text">
  <div class="marquee">
    <span>text 1</span>
    <span>text 2</span>
    <span>text 1</span>
    <span>text 2</span>
    <span>text 1</span>
    <span>text 2</span>
    <span>text 1</span>
    <span>text 2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

а чтобы разметка осталась такой

```html
<div class="text">
  <div class="marquee">
    <span>text 1</span>
    <span>text 2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не понятен вопрос. Что именно ты хочешь реализовать? Опиши суть проблемы более подробно

Comment: @Air, бесконечную бегую строку. Сейчас спаны приходится дублировать

Comment: Это не так делается. Можно использовать псевдо элементы или повтор нужен один и бесконечная анимация